# How to print a diagonal line in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to make a diagonal line in C like trying to make a pyramid.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char builder = get_char("Building Material: ");
    int size = get_int("Line Size: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = size - 1; j < i + size; j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%c\n", builder);
    }
}
```

It's my best one so far yet I still can't fix how the spaces should be added.

> I don't wanna make a pyramid.

What's the problem here?

Comment: I got [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mYZLqWh6O4mtKHke) by replacing `j--` to `j++`. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where exactly your problem is. You stated too less about the issue you have with your code.

Just as a side note:

You use very much redundant code. If you want to print the diagonal line from top right to bottom left, you can simplify the code like this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char builder = get_char("Building Material: ");
    int size = get_int("Line Size: ");

    for ( ; 0 < size ; size-- )
    {
        printf("%*c\n", size, builder);
    }
}
```

The `*` is used to set the width.

Example input:

```
Building Material: c
Size: 12
```

Example output:

```
           c
          c
         c
        c
       c
      c
     c
    c
   c
  c
 c
c
```

Answer (score 0):

One such way would be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char builder = '#';
    int size = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if(j == i)
                printf("%c", builder);
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe;
#
 #
  #
   #
    #
```